# removing error bars and connecting lines from a matplotlib generated line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I used the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax.plot(x2, y2)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

to generate the following graph:

[image]

is there anyway by which I can remove all those extra lines that are making the graph difficult to read. Note: I tried `linestyle = 'None'` but all lines on  the graph disappeared.

[image]

Below is a sample of the data that generated the graph:

```
x1 = ['Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 ...]

y1 = [-56,
 -56,
 0,
 -39,
 -94,
 -106,
 -111,
 -100,
 -67,
 -56,
 -22,
 -17,
 -83,
 -128,
 -144,
 -150,
 -189,
 -217,
 -300,
 -156,
 -178,
 -178,
 -250,
 -267,
 -228,
 -206,
 -239,
 -250,
 -222,
 -217,
 -167,
 -211,
 -167,
 -167,
 -156,
 -128,
 -89,
 -56,
 -33,
 -78,
 -111,
 -122,
 -83,
 -56,
 -28,
 -11,
 -83,
 -133,
 -150,
 -139,
 -89,
 -89,
 -78,
 -122,
 -128,
 -128,
 -144,
 -161,
 -100,
 -117,
 -172,
 -211,
 -178,
 -150,
 -111,
 -144,
 -122,
 -144,
 -156,
 -100,
 -122,
 -144,
 -161,
 -106,
 -122,
 -128,
 -100,
 -89,
 -33,
 -22,
 -61,
 -50,
 -50,
 -33,
 -61,
 -44,
 -22,
 -33,
 -28,
 -11,
 -22,
 -67,
 -6,
 -39,
 11,
 -11,
 -6,
 -22,
 -17,
 6,
 17,
 17,
 0,
 -28,
 -22,
 -17,
 6,
 -6,
 11,
 11,
 -6,
 -6,
 -56,
 78,
 61,
 39,
 50,
 33,
 50,
 44,
 83,
 56,
 72,
 89,
 106,
 133,
 128,
 150,
 133,
 161,
 156,
 167,
 194,
 200,
 183,
 161,
 61,
 56,
 61,
 89,
 56,
 44,
 100,
 78,
 39,
 83,
 161,
 183,
 172,
 183,
 178,
 172,
 100,
 78,
 94,
 83,
 50,
 128,
 106,
 50,
 106,
 111,
 133,
 156,
 178,
 133,
 167,
 200,
 200,
 194,
 139,
 117,
 139,
 161,
 133,
 144,
 189,
 139,
 111,
 100,
 94,
 111,
 78,
 133,
 156,
 161,
 72,
 144,
 133,
 122,
 122,
 150,
 167,
 167,
 172,
 144,
 150,
 139,
 78,
 122,
 128,
 144,
 139,
 111,
 83,
 100,
 72,
 83,
 100,
 50,
 67,
 111,
 122,
 133,
 111,
 89,
 72,
 83,
 72,
 89,
 72,
 56,
 94,
 78,
 72,
 94,
 39,
 89,
 111,
 83,
 100,
 83,
 94,
 94,
 78,
 94,
 50,
 111,
 94,
 67,
 39,
 44,
 11,
 -6,
 11,
 39,
 50,
 100,
 100,
 61,
 61,
 33,
 22,
 22,
 17,
 67,
 83,
 56,
 56,
 -6,
 -33,
 -11,
 -6,
 -22,
 0,
 -33,
 -33,
 0,
 -11,
 -22,
 -61,
 -50,
 -72,
 -61,
 -39,
 -11,
 -22,
 -6,
 6,
 17,
 6,
 -28,
 -11,
 22,
 -39,
 -67,
 -44,
 -44,
 -50,
 -17,
 -56,
 -122,
 -122,
 -89,
 -50,
 -44,
 -78,
 -111,
 -128,
 -156,
 -122,
 -67,
 0,
 -39,
 -56,
 -56,
 -89,
 -94,
 -78,
 -150,
 -183,
 -194,
 -200,
 -189,
 -122,
 -167,
 -178,
 -178,
 -156,
 -83,
 -111,
 -189,
 -183,
 -161,
 -167,
 -144,
 -139,
 -128,
 -44,
 -56,
 -11,
 -22,
 -28,
 -11,
 -28,
 -56,
 -39,
 -11,
 0,
 17,
 -67,
 -78,
 -78,
 -44,
 -50,
 -60,
 -50,
 -17,
 -33,
 -78,
 -83,
 -67,
 -122,
 -67,
 -72,
 -83,
 -78,
 -106,
 -94,
 -67,
 -50,
 -106,
 -78,
 -83,
 -28,
 -17,
 -39,
 -39,
 -67,
 -32,
 -27,
 -61,
 -67,
 -83,
 -144,
 -144,
 -128,
 -139,
 -182,
 -144,
 -94,
 -67,
 -56,
 -172,
 -178,
 -178,
 -178,
 -161,
 -89,
 -100,
 -178,
 -117,
 -111,
 -139,
 -143,
 -133,
 -89,
 -105,
 -100,
 -105,
 -94,
 -122,
 -128,
 -22,
 -67,
 -32,
 11,
 -72,
 -33,
 -94,
 -56,
 -67,
 -72,
 -67,
 -78,
 -78,
 -67,
 -72,
 -72,
 -44,
 -61,
 -82,
 -72,
 -50,
 -38,
 -22,
 44,
 17,
 -22,
 -72,
 -72,
 -22,
 -22,
 -44,
 -50,
 -44,
 -17,
 -11,
 44,
 50,
 50,
 39,
 -6,
 6,
 11,
 17,
 -11,
 28,
 44,
 28,
 28,
 17,
 22,
 6,
 0,
 17,
 56,
 117,
 89,
 89,
 89,
 167,
 172,
 150,
 78,
 94,
 39,
 50,
 78,
 67,
 67,
 117,
 50,
 28,
 44,
 61,
 83,
 61,
 89,
 117,
 139,
 133,
 117,
 122,
 50,
 100,
 100,
 78,
 117,
 122,
 100,
 100,
 106,
 100,
 144,
 128,
 111,
 89,
 67,
 78,
 100,
 122,
 172,
 89,
 111,
 139,
 139,
 156,
 156,
 172,
 106,
 133,
 117,
 161,
 133,
 111,
 100,
 128,
 122,
 183,
 183,
 178,
 183,
 206,
 206,
 217,
 167,
 139,
 139,
 139,
 150,
 133,
 111,
 117,
 89,
 67,
 78,
 94,
 89,
 72,
 94,
 133,
 150,
 100,
 61,
 106,
 111,
 133,
 156,
 122,
 144,
 150,
 150,
 128,
 106,
 133,
 117,
 94,
 78,
 94,
 100,
 106,
 100,
 100,
 106,
 72,
 100,
 150,
 100,
 78,
 89,
 94,
 83,
 67,
 28,
 -5,
 0,
 83,
 39,
 11,
 6,
 33,
 6,
 -21,
 6,
 33,
 6,
 33,
 44,
 -22,
 0,
 -6,
 -10,
 6,
 39,
 0,
 -17,
 -56,
 -28,
 -61,
 -33,
 33,
 72,
 0,
 17,
 6,
 11,
 -17,
 -44,
 -39,
 -50,
 -44,
 -6,
 -38,
 -61,
 -28,
 -49,
 -82,
 -89,
 -93,
 -56,
 -27,
 -6,
 44,
 0,
 -6,
 -17,
 -27,
 -28,
 -32,
 -6,
 -6,
 -67,
 6,
 -39,
 -61,
 -77,
 -78,
 -61,
 -56,
 -60,
 -39,
 11,
 22,
 39,
 -6,
 -28,
 -67,
 -78,
 -122,
 -116,
 -122,
 -89,
 -94,
 -100,
 -89,
 -78,
 17,
 -17,
 -22,
 -22,
 -32,
 -17,
 -50,
 -88,
 -82,
 -67,
 11,
 17,
 -33,
 -22,
 -33,
 -39,
 -28,
 -28,
 -11,
 -33,
 -44,
 -61,
 -39,
 -17,
 17,
 -44,
 -67,
 -50,
 -72,
 -78,
 -94,
 -100,
 -33,
 -28,
 -100,
 -139,
 -144,
 -122,
 -122,
 -138,
 -139,
 -82,
 -78,
 -111,
 -177,
 -233,
 -106,
 -189,
 -183,
 -156,
 -171,
 -161,
 -183,
 -217,
 -222,
 -244,
 -239,
 -233,
 -200,
 -210,
 -194,
 -172,
 -139,
 -139,
 -217,
 -256,
 -222,
 -189,
 -199,
 -188,
 -106,
 -105,
 -106,
 89,
 117,
 72,
 50,
 67,
 122,
 144,
 150,
 133,
 161,
 100,
 61,
 28,
 17,
 83,
 67,
 67,
 94,
 89,
 117,
 122,
 117,
 89,
 128,
 167,
 106,
 72,
 100,
 78,
 61,
 67,
 106,
 133,
 161,
 122,
 100,
 72,
 67,
 44,
 78,
 100,
 133,
 117,
 106,
 133,
 189,
 172,
 111,
 106,
 39,
 61,
 89,
 78,
 117,
 139,
 122,
 83,
 50,
 72,
 89,
 111,
 128,
 117,
 133,
 156,
 133,
 111,
 144,
 133,
 178,
 144,
 122,
 128,
 150,
 200,
 183,
 183,
 156,
 133,
 133,
 117,
 100,
 89,
 128,
 72,
 44,
 78,
 122,
 122,
 133,
 178,
 161,
 128,
 106,
 100,
 106,
 133,
 83,
 78,
 61,
 67,
 94,
 100,
 133,
 122,
 144,
 150,
 139,
 117,
 56,
 50,
 61,
 83,
 111,
 83,
 ...]

x2 = ['Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Oct',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Nov',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Dec',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Jan',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Feb',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Mar',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'Apr',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'May',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'June',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'July',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Aug',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 'Sept',
 ...]

y2 = [156,
 139,
 133,
 39,
 33,
 0,
 6,
 17,
 28,
 44,
 44,
 139,
 161,
 150,
 -33,
 -33,
 -50,
 -33,
 11,
 11,
 -39,
 -72,
 -44,
 11,
 28,
 28,
 6,
 -11,
 17,
 28,
 33,
 17,
 17,
 61,
 67,
 89,
 78,
 67,
 67,
 39,
 6,
 33,
 100,
 94,
 94,
 117,
 100,
 50,
 -17,
 22,
 28,
 61,
 39,
 39,
 28,
 11,
 22,
 11,
 44,
 39,
 -11,
 17,
 44,
 78,
 194,
 139,
 139,
 -6,
 61,
 33,
 28,
 39,
 39,
 56,
 78,
 67,
 50,
 117,
 50,
 56,
 94,
 94,
 106,
 100,
 89,
 139,
 167,
 183,
 239,
 233,
 200,
 133,
 156,
 200,
 256,
 272,
 267,
 189,
 200,
 233,
 228,
 183,
 172,
 206,
 206,
 244,
 244,
 272,
 289,
 289,
 250,
 156,
 111,
 156,
 178,
 167,
 156,
 156,
 144,
 144,
 156,
 144,
 122,
 167,
 172,
 228,
 233,
 250,
 289,
 294,
 294,
 233,
 228,
 228,
 200,
 156,
 200,
 228,
 217,
 233,
 261,
 261,
 217,
 217,
 239,
 261,
 261,
 256,
 228,
 239,
 272,
 272,
 272,
 267,
 311,
 344,
 344,
 344,
 350,
 350,
 350,
 350,
 317,
 306,
 317,
 328,
 289,
 228,
 228,
 267,
 283,
 311,
 306,
 317,
 367,
 372,
 378,
 361,
 356,
 339,
 339,
 317,
 294,
 294,
 350,
 361,
 300,
 317,
 300,
 317,
 328,
 328,
 350,
 339,
 333,
 328,
 317,
 383,
 333,
 322,
 328,
 328,
 322,
 317,
 339,
 339,
 344,
 333,
 272,
 289,
 289,
 300,
 333,
 333,
 361,
 339,
 339,
 311,
 317,
 333,
 333,
 322,
 322,
 328,
 333,
 289,
 283,
 300,
 306,
 306,
 317,
 322,
 300,
 294,
 289,
 289,
 300,
 300,
 317,
 317,
 322,
 322,
 317,
 294,
 300,
 294,
 289,
 272,
 294,
 306,
 311,
 289,
 306,
 328,
 328,
 333,
 333,
 311,
 261,
 233,
 278,
 289,
 278,
 300,
 311,
 311,
 311,
 283,
 278,
 256,
 256,
 261,
 222,
 261,
 289,
 311,
 311,
 306,
 294,
 289,
 278,
 183,
 183,
 172,
 172,
 211,
 250,
 239,
 206,
 183,
 222,
 222,
 211,
 150,
 156,
 206,
 139,
 211,
 122,
 144,
 144,
 167,
 189,
 206,
 194,
 183,
 222,
 250,
 228,
 200,
 183,
 200,
 217,
 222,
 200,
 206,
 206,
 189,
 200,
 183,
 61,
 44,
 122,
 128,
 128,
 67,
 28,
 33,
 -6,
 50,
 117,
 200,
 206,
 83,
 11,
 0,
 -6,
 22,
 11,
 -22,
 -33,
 -11,
 -11,
 0,
 33,
 22,
 -6,
 11,
 17,
 17,
 -11,
 -28,
 -33,
 -22,
 -22,
 28,
 50,
 61,
 61,
 50,
 39,
 72,
 56,
 39,
 28,
 39,
 44,
 61,
 72,
 72,
 33,
 17,
 56,
 67,
 56,
 83,
 128,
 128,
 117,
 33,
 28,
 106,
 111,
 106,
 133,
 133,
 117,
 56,
 56,
 39,
 39,
 78,
 122,
 128,
 128,
 122,
 106,
 106,
 89,
 83,
 39,
 22,
 17,
 -6,
 17,
 17,
 22,
 17,
 17,
 106,
 100,
 144,
 156,
 6,
 -33,
 17,
 56,
 106,
 122,
 111,
 89,
 44,
 17,
 33,
 44,
 39,
 17,
 56,
 61,
 61,
 83,
 111,
 167,
 94,
 122,
 122,
 139,
 206,
 222,
 261,
 167,
 144,
 167,
 156,
 172,
 167,
 133,
 144,
 189,
 250,
 244,
 261,
 278,
 272,
 239,
 206,
 194,
 222,
 250,
 261,
 261,
 267,
 206,
 200,
 200,
 211,
 211,
 200,
 228,
 222,
 228,
 256,
 256,
 250,
 217,
 211,
 239,
 239,
 244,
 244,
 228,
 133,
 183,
 167,
 189,
 239,
 239,
 189,
 217,
 217,
 206,
 244,
 267,
 289,
 306,
 311,
 333,
 344,
 350,
 322,
 333,
 300,
 267,
 261,
 283,
 294,
 300,
 283,
 289,
 278,
 217,
 228,
 250,
 256,
 278,
 322,
 333,
 339,
 300,
 294,
 272,
 289,
 300,
 267,
 278,
 283,
 283,
 289,
 289,
 278,
 333,
 328,
 278,
 300,
 317,
 283,
 283,
 283,
 294,
 306,
 306,
 289,
 300,
 306,
 339,
 361,
 350,
 333,
 300,
 294,
 300,
 306,
 289,
 306,
 306,
 311,
 311,
 306,
 339,
 339,
 350,
 356,
 361,
 350,
 317,
 317,
 317,
 317,
 322,
 294,
 306,
 289,
 272,
 289,
 294,
 294,
 300,
 306,
 306,
 311,
 283,
 283,
 300,
 306,
 300,
 300,
 311,
 294,
 278,
 261,
 261,
 267,
 256,
 244,
 239,
 250,
 256,
 267,
 278,
 294,
 300,
 283,
 228,
 261,
 250,
 267,
 233,
 250,
 289,
 283,
 239,
 200,
 200,
 200,
 233,
 244,
 228,
 233,
 244,
 244,
 233,
 178,
 217,
 272,
 272,
 272,
 217,
 206,
 206,
 239,
 256,
 256,
 206,
 206,
 150,
 128,
 144,
 150,
 161,
 189,
 200,
 122,
 172,
 178,
 139,
 94,
 111,
 111,
 111,
 89,
 133,
 222,
 228,
 206,
 117,
 94,
 94,
 128,
 172,
 172,
 222,
 256,
 211,
 217,
 128,
 61,
 78,
 83,
 89,
 83,
 67,
 61,
 67,
 72,
 106,
 133,
 144,
 172,
 183,
 183,
 183,
 200,
 189,
 183,
 72,
 39,
 22,
 22,
 67,
 67,
 -11,
 44,
 111,
 128,
 133,
 111,
 128,
 128,
 122,
 144,
 156,
 94,
 72,
 78,
 133,
 133,
 100,
 89,
 61,
 61,
 83,
 94,
 111,
 139,
 128,
 111,
 100,
 106,
 128,
 133,
 94,
 72,
 ...]
```

Note: all lists are of the same length

Comment: [Please do not add images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: You can sort the month list or `x` to make sure that a line doesn't cross itself.

Comment: the list is sorted

Comment: Could you please add the data that generated the plot or share a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I added a sample of data from each list. The months are in order for 10 consecutive years (x1 and x2) y1 and y2 are the min and max temperatures for a  given month

Comment: `x1` is not actually sorted: you can see `Jan` comes up after `Dec` which is creating the necessary connecting lines. Do you want to plot month-wise change in the temperature?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this might help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np


x1 = ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'June', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'July', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept', 'Sept']
y1 = [-56, -56, 0, -39, -94, -106, -111, -100, -67, -56, -22, -17, -83, -128, -144, -150, -189, -217, -300, -156, -178, -178, -250, -267, -228, -206, -239, -250, -222, -217, -167, -211, -167, -167, -156, -128, -89, -56, -33, -78, -111, -122, -83, -56, -28, -11, -83, -133, -150, -139, -89, -89, -78, -122, -128, -128, -144, -161, -100, -117, -172, -211, -178, -150, -111, -144, -122, -144, -156, -100, -122, -144, -161, -106, -122, -128, -100, -89, -33, -22, -61, -50, -50, -33, -61, -44, -22, -33, -28, -11, -22, -67, -6, -39, 11, -11, -6, -22, -17, 6, 17, 17, 0, -28, -22, -17, 6, -6, 11, 11, -6, -6, -56, 78, 61, 39, 50, 33, 50, 44, 83, 56, 72, 89, 106, 133, 128, 150, 133, 161, 156, 167, 194, 200, 183, 161, 61, 56, 61, 89, 56, 44, 100, 78, 39, 83, 161, 183, 172, 183, 178, 172, 100, 78, 94, 83, 50, 128, 106, 50, 106, 111, 133, 156, 178, 133, 167, 200, 200, 194, 139, 117, 139, 161, 133, 144, 189, 139, 111, 100, 94, 111, 78, 133, 156, 161, 72, 144, 133, 122, 122, 150, 167, 167, 172, 144, 150, 139, 78, 122, 128, 144, 139, 111, 83, 100, 72, 83, 100, 50, 67, 111, 122, 133, 111, 89, 72, 83, 72, 89, 72, 56, 94, 78, 72, 94, 39, 89, 111, 83, 100, 83, 94, 94, 78, 94, 50, 111, 94, 67, 39, 44, 11, -6, 11, 39, 50, 100, 100, 61, 61, 33, 22, 22, 17, 67, 83, 56, 56, -6, -33, -11, -6, -22, 0, -33, -33, 0, -11, -22, -61, -50, -72, -61, -39, -11, -22, -6, 6, 17, 6, -28, -11, 22, -39, -67, -44, -44, -50, -17, -56, -122, -122, -89, -50, -44, -78, -111, -128, -156, -122, -67, 0, -39, -56, -56, -89, -94, -78, -150, -183, -194, -200, -189, -122, -167, -178, -178, -156, -83, -111, -189, -183, -161, -167, -144, -139, -128, -44, -56, -11, -22, -28, -11, -28, -56, -39, -11, 0, 17, -67, -78, -78, -44, -50, -60, -50, -17, -33, -78, -83, -67, -122, -67, -72, -83, -78, -106, -94, -67, -50, -106, -78, -83, -28, -17, -39, -39, -67, -32, -27, -61, -67, -83, -144, -144, -128, -139, -182, -144, -94, -67, -56, -172, -178, -178, -178, -161, -89, -100, -178, -117, -111, -139, -143, -133, -89, -105, -100, -105, -94, -122, -128, -22, -67, -32, 11, -72, -33, -94, -56, -67, -72, -67, -78, -78, -67, -72, -72, -44, -61, -82, -72, -50, -38, -22, 44, 17, -22, -72, -72, -22, -22, -44, -50, -44, -17, -11, 44, 50, 50, 39, -6, 6, 11, 17, -11, 28, 44, 28, 28, 17, 22, 6, 0, 17, 56, 117, 89, 89, 89, 167, 172, 150, 78, 94, 39, 50, 78, 67, 67, 117, 50, 28, 44, 61, 83, 61, 89, 117, 139, 133, 117, 122, 50, 100, 100, 78, 117, 122, 100, 100, 106, 100, 144, 128, 111, 89, 67, 78, 100, 122, 172, 89, 111, 139, 139, 156, 156, 172, 106, 133, 117, 161, 133, 111, 100, 128, 122, 183, 183, 178, 183, 206, 206, 217, 167, 139, 139, 139, 150, 133, 111, 117, 89, 67, 78, 94, 89, 72, 94, 133, 150, 100, 61, 106, 111, 133, 156, 122, 144, 150, 150, 128, 106, 133, 117, 94, 78, 94, 100, 106, 100, 100, 106, 72, 100, 150, 100, 78, 89, 94, 83, 67, 28, -5, 0, 83, 39, 11, 6, 33, 6, -21, 6, 33, 6, 33, 44, -22, 0, -6, -10, 6, 39, 0, -17, -56, -28, -61, -33, 33, 72, 0, 17, 6, 11, -17, -44, -39, -50, -44, -6, -38, -61, -28, -49, -82, -89, -93, -56, -27, -6, 44, 0, -6, -17, -27, -28, -32, -6, -6, -67, 6, -39, -61, -77, -78, -61, -56, -60, -39, 11, 22, 39, -6, -28, -67, -78, -122, -116, -122, -89, -94, -100, -89, -78, 17, -17, -22, -22, -32, -17, -50, -88, -82, -67, 11, 17, -33, -22, -33, -39, -28, -28, -11, -33, -44, -61, -39, -17, 17, -44, -67, -50, -72, -78, -94, -100, -33, -28, -100, -139, -144, -122, -122, -138, -139, -82, -78, -111, -177, -233, -106, -189, -183, -156, -171, -161, -183, -217, -222, -244, -239, -233, -200, -210, -194, -172, -139, -139, -217, -256, -222, -189, -199, -188, -106, -105, -106, 89, 117, 72, 50, 67, 122, 144, 150, 133, 161, 100, 61, 28, 17, 83, 67, 67, 94, 89, 117, 122, 117, 89, 128, 167, 106, 72, 100, 78, 61, 67, 106, 133, 161, 122, 100, 72, 67, 44, 78, 100, 133, 117, 106, 133, 189, 172, 111, 106, 39, 61, 89, 78, 117, 139, 122, 83, 50, 72, 89, 111, 128, 117, 133, 156, 133, 111, 144, 133, 178, 144, 122, 128, 150, 200, 183, 183, 156, 133, 133, 117, 100, 89, 128, 72, 44, 78, 122, 122, 133, 178, 161, 128, 106, 100, 106, 133, 83, 78, 61, 67, 94, 100, 133, 122, 144, 150, 139, 117, 56, 50, 61, 83, 111, 83]


# Select data of equal length from the given lists
x2 = x1[0:500]
y2 = y1[0:500]


# Change x2 to create year-wise month names
x4 = []

which_year = -1
for i in range(len(x2) - 1):
    if x2[i] == "Dec" and x2[i+1] == "Jan":
        x4.append(x2[i] + str(which_year))
        which_year += 1
    else:
        x4.append(x2[i] + str(which_year))

# Get xtick positions 
xposlabels = [x4.index(month_year) for month_year in np.unique(x4)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y2)
ax.set_xticks(xposlabels, labels = np.unique(x4).tolist(), rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it worked but the x labels are now overlapping since the actual data is for 10 consecutive years, is there a way by which I can increase the padding between each xtick label that they're more readable?

Comment: There are many posts on SO that might help you with this. For example, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683694/matplotlib-labels-are-overlapping).